# Alternative for union in SQL where-clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

in `where` clause i am using like

```
SELECT name 
  FROM products 
 WHERE id IN (
           SELECT product_id 
             FROM orders 
            UNION 
           SELECT 1);
```

it taking time to perform `union`.

please provide some other alternative to improve my query performance

Answer (score 5):

what about

```
select name from products
where id in (select product_id from orders)
    or id = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

A `union` removes duplicates, and SQL Server may unfortunately not be able to spot that such removal is not required when the result of the `union` is being used in an `IN` predicate.

```
SELECT name 
  FROM products 
 WHERE id IN (
           SELECT product_id 
             FROM orders 
            UNION ALL
           SELECT 1);
```

`UNION ALL` says that duplicates are allowed, so it will avoid the expensive step of removing duplicates. Even though you may think that, because the second part of the union only has one value, the duplicate check should be quick, this isn't so. `UNION` says that *all* duplicates must be eliminated. It has to eliminate all the duplicate product_ids from the first part of the query also.

---

I've just done a few quick tests, and found one repro where the optimizer isn't smart enough to avoid duplicate removal, for versions 2000, 2005, 2008. All 3 show a query plan that shows a distinct sort being used after concatenation between a table scan (of `#IDs`) and a constant scan:

```
create table #IDs (
    ID int not null
)
go
insert into #IDs (ID)
select 1 union all
select 1 union all
select 2 union all
select 2 union all
select 3
go
select * from sysobjects where id in (select ID from #IDs union select 1)
go
```

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Jeez- I've been using SQL for 8 years and didn't know `UNION` removed duplicates. I just always used `UNION ALL`. You learn something every day!

Comment: That would be true in all(?) circumstances but this one. Since the result of the sub-query is used with an `IN` clause, SQL Server query optimizer is smart enough to remove the "distinct sort" step from the query plan. The query plan in this case is identical with `ALL` and without.

Comment: @all: The IN would ignore any duplicates created by UNION ALL, but a DISTINCT operation wouldbe removed from the plan

Comment: @gbn - There is no DISTINCT operation in the query plan when using UNION.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: I was going to say "stream aggregate" but changed. It should be "effective DISTINCT". And generally UNION *does* have one to remove duplicates, UNION ALL doesn't. Whether this persists into the IN/EXISTS clauses depends on the optimiser

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I just tested on SQL Server 2008 and 2005, no "stream aggregate". Well, first learning experience of the day

Comment: @gbn - just updated answer with an example I can repro on 2000-2008 that includes a "distinct sort" op.

Comment: @Damien: 2008 R2 doesn't seem to be performing distinct sort here. Plans are identical for both `union` and `union all` versions.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following query. Most efficient of the lot.

```
select name from products P
where P.id = 1 or 
exists 
(select TOP 1 '1' from orders O
where O.product_id = P.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select p1.name from products as p1
    inner join orders as o on o.product_id = p1.id
union
select p2.name from products as p2 where p2.id = 1;
```

Comment: A join is the only way to do this query